# Cocos2d-x-3.1.1 gives error while running build_native.py

Tags: android, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

```
python G:/ace/proj.android/build_native.py all 
E:\android' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
The Selected NDK toolchain version was 4.8 !
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "G:/ace/proj.android/build_native.py", line 166, in <module>
build(opts.ndk_build_param,opts.android_platform,opts.build_mode)
File "G:/ace/proj.android/build_native.py", line 153, in build
do_build(cocos_root, ndk_root,         app_android_root,ndk_build_param,sdk_root,android_platform,build_mode)
File "G:/ace/proj.android/build_native.py", line 89, in do_build
raise Exception("Build dynamic library for project [ " + app_android_root + " ]   fails!")
```

Exception: Build dynamic library for project [ G:\ace\proj.android ] fails!

This is the error, all paths are set and everything is up to date, NDK is R9D (64 bit) sdk etc all updated. I don't know know to fix this, on windows 7 64 bit, with eclipse and Cocos2d-x-3.1.1, all the paths are set using setup.py and verified working by running the setup.py

Thanks

Comment: E:\android .... perhaps a path/folder that contains a space? Avoid spaces for development paths, many coders unfortunately still live in the 80s, assuming a "space-free environment".

Comment: I have no space in any path, also no such folder in E drive, so i don't know why it's saying that.

Answer (score 2):

Fixed , there was space in NDK folder, please if you have this issue remove spaces in all folders you work with.

Comment: what you do i can't understand it... would you explain it